# Face glitch on the back of Black Plasma rig

Tags: bones, edit-mode, rigify

I have just started to use Blender and when I wanted to add a character into my scene using Black Plasma Rig V2 (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BqROFnoZTpTu5X09v-SPYaYlZqjMINDh/view). The back of the head is supposed to have hair but it has a face instead. This only happens when the facial features are activated on this skin. This only accrues with this skin too, I test around 10 skins. I also test with deleting the 2nd layer and using a skin without a second layer and still no luck. I have looked at people with similar question but the only solution that might still help would be going into edit mode and moving the eyes and mouth out but I couldn't find a way to do this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and upload images that show your 
current setup and illustrate the problem.See [How to upload an image 
to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Why have you removed the link to the blend file? External links are fine, they just shouldn't be the _*only*_ source for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Black Plasma Rig is a 2.79 blend that needs a few adjustments for Blender 2.8+.

There are two issues:

**1. Fixing the Missing Transparency**

As shown in the screenshots of the question the model is shown pitch black in *Eevee* and *Material Preview* mode. To fix this, go to the *Material Properties > Settings* and set *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Clip*. Done this, the model is textured properly and you can see the second problem. The character has a face texture on the back of his head.

[image: screenshot 1 alpha clip]

**2. Fixing the Double Face Head**

To fix this you need to separate the mesh of the character's face and head and remove the *UV Project* from the head mesh.

Note: If you prefer the Blender 2.8 layout you can create a new workspace with the [+] at the end of the main menu/workspaces list. You can also enable the *Restriction Toggles* in the filter menu for the outliner (see the last screenshot).

[image: fixing the head texture]

In the outliner, expand the armature and look for *Main Body > Face*. (Selection is restricted if you haven't enabled it as noted but you can still select it with a click.) Select the *Face* object, and switch to *Edit* mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Switch the front view (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or use *View > Viewport > Front*), press <kbd>T</kbd> to show the tool icons. Now box select the character's face but unselect (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click) the eyes on the back on his head so only his face is selected.

[image: separated meshes and the modifier]

Separate the selected mesh with <kbd>P</kbd>, and choose *Selection*. This will create another object *Face.001* in the outliner. *Face* is now the head without the character's face.

With the *Face* object still selected, go to the *Modifier* tab and remove the *UVProject* modifier from the head (=*Face* object).

The head is now fixed:

[image: fixed result]
(Blender 2.8 workspace layout and *Restriction Toggles* enabled to remove the selection restrictions.)

Comment: Thank you for you help Blunder. I was able to fix the double face glitch with your help.